# Как расширить SVG без растяжки углов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Есть svg, и нужно чтобы она растягивалась именно по ширине, без изменения высоты, это я реализовал с помощью preserveAspectRatio="none". Но при растяжке компонента эти углы ломаются, как можно сделать так, чтобы при изменении ширины экрана углы не ломались?

Код компонента тут-> https://pastebin.com/FhLCFjrD

[image: Вот так должен выглядеть компонент]

[image: Это если его увеличивать, при уменьшении он почти как прямоугольник становится]

Comment: Задачка непростая, но в принципе решаемая. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547993

Comment: Сделать svg из трех кусков. Растягивать только средний.